# Solve javascript counter dilemma in C

Tags: javascript, c, closures, function-pointers

I came across below [example in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp), while learning about javascript closures. I was wondering if this could be achieved in **C programming**, since we have similar **function pointers** in C. However, I was not able to completely achieve this with simple pointers to function implementation. Can someone please give it a try? Redirect me if it has already been asked.

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// the counter is now 3
```

Comment: Tried returning a function from another, but I coundn't access the counter from outside of it. Also, I couldn't define a function inside another since well, it's C.

Comment: Then please edit your question and show that, even it if is wrong.

Comment: @goodbytes Include your attempts in the question, not in the comments, since _the question has to include your attempts_.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I don't really know what you'll learn from the attempt on a question that asks "is this even possible?" (especially when the answer is, in absence of someone smarter than me, a rather resounding thud of a "nope").

Comment: @Amadan question includes this : " I was not able to completely achieve this....", that suggested that the OP has tried something.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, not really. A closure is, effectively, a structure that consists of a function pointer, if you will, *and the captured state* (the variables that are closed over). You cannot capture state in C. You could fake a closure by explicitly defining a structure to hold state, and explicitly passing this structure in to the function; but then a) it gets messy, and b) what's the point of not passing `counter` when you need to pass a struct with `counter`?

Your specific code could be done by explicitly defining `counter` as a static variable; but it is not generalisable to what closure really is.

EDIT: Apparently there is a mechanism to pass the structure for you: FFCALL. It is still ugly. Anyway, moving to close as duplicate.